# How to use -highlight-color in MagickImage?

Tags: imagemagick

SetLowlightColor does not work!

```
 using (IMagickImage img1 = new MagickImage(Path.Combine(fullpath, IMAGE1)))
        {
            using (IMagickImage img2 = new MagickImage(Path.Combine(fullpath, IMAGE2)))
            {
                using (IMagickImage imgDiff = new MagickImage())
                {
                    img1.ColorFuzz = new Percentage(fuzz);                       
                    imgDiff.SetLowlightColor(new MagickColor(Color.Blue)); 
                    double diff = img1.Compare(img2, ErrorMetric.Absolute, imgDiff);


                    imgDiff.Write(result);
                }
            }
        }
```

https://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/compare/

Comment: It looks like you found a bug. And I think I will need to refactor the SetLowLightColor method. Would you mind opening an issue here: https://github.com/dlemstra/Magick.NET?

Answer (score 0):

It appears that you have discovered a bug in the Magick.NET library. I just published version 7.1.0.0 of the library to resolve your issue. But I have also decided to move the `SetLowlightColor` from the `MagickImage` class and introduce a new class called `CompareSettings` where you can set the `Lowlightcolor`. This property is moved because it is only used by the compare method. Your code should be changed to this:

```
using (IMagickImage img1 = new MagickImage(Path.Combine(fullpath, IMAGE1)))
{
    using (IMagickImage img2 = new MagickImage(Path.Combine(fullpath, IMAGE2)))
    {
        using (IMagickImage imgDiff = new MagickImage())
        {
            img1.ColorFuzz = new Percentage(fuzz);
            CompareSettings settings = new CompareSettings()
            {
                Metric = ErrorMetric.Absolute,
                LowlightColor = MagickColors.Blue
            };
            double diff = img1.Compare(img2, settings, imgDiff);

            imgDiff.Write(result);
        }
    }
}
```